# Unable to print boarding passed for connecting flight to Azores (YYZ - PDL flight)

Tags: air-travel, check-in, yyz

I am flying to Toronto via Delta to take the flight with Azores Airlines (I used this airlines once before to fly from Azores a year ago).

However, when I attempted to do online check-in, it told me that I was checked-in but warned me that I cannot print boarding passes - "Some boarding passes cannot be printed. You can collect your boarding passes at a check-in desk at the airport."

Now what do I do? I guess I have about 2 hours between those flyings. Would I need to exit the terminal area to check-in at Azores kiosk?

Or would I have to exit the arriving terminal anyways to get the departing terminal for Azores?

Comment: At a check-in desk of whatever airport it is that you are flying from?! Since also there your luggage (if any) will/would be checked through. And even if not, they would be able to tell you where to get your boarding passes.

Answer (score 4):

Your first choice should be the **check-in desk at the airport where you board the flight TO Toronto**.

These days, airlines that interline at all usually interline enough to be able to print boarding passes for connecting flights, so chances are excellent that Delta will be able to print a boarding pass for Azores. (This all assumes both flights are on a single booking, of course).

If you're pressed for time at your departure airport, or Delta can't print a boarding pass for you, you get a second chance at the **Azores check-in desk or kiosk at Toronto**.

You don't tell us where you're coming from, but all Delta's flights to Toronto originate in the US. Like most North American airports, Toronto Pearson does not have an international transit area, so as an arriving passenger on an international flight, you will need to pass through Canadian immigration, and then end up landside. On your way to the departures security check you can go to the Azores check-in desks and get your boarding card printed.

(**Note, though,** phoog's experience in comments below, which partly contradicts this. However, you can still generally expect that *if* an airport provides a separate path for transfer passengers, *then* there will also be a transfer desk where you can have your boarding pass issued somewhere on that path, if you need a boarding pass to reach the departure gate -- or you can get it at the gate otherwise. You'll want to ask the Delta cabin crew for advice on your way to Toronto if you don't have the boarding card by then).

According to Wikipedia, both Delta and Azores use terminal 3 at Toronto.

Comment: I made a transit in Toronto last summer, and if I recall correctly I went through an immigration checkpoint for transit passengers (with only two desks -- that part I remember clearly) that led me to the secure area of the airport.  There I was able to eat breakfast and proceed to my gate without additional screening or boarding pass check.  In that case, the second choice would therefore be the agent at the gate.

Comment: @phoog: Interesting. I'll admit I based that part of the answer simply on a Timatic lookup saying transiting passengers at YYZ need sufficient documents to enter Canada. Do you remember whether you had to show an onwards boarding card before you could queue up for the transit immigration check? There may have been a transfer desk _before_ that point.

Comment: I don't remember.  I had been up packing the night before, having to leave at 3 or 4 am, so I slept for the entire flight from New York to Toronto and was very groggy as a result.  I would imagine that there would be some way of getting the passenger through the transit desk without a boarding pass, though, either escorted by an airline employee or by printing a boarding pass at a transfer desk.